# Static link to latest version of picture on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, versioning, file, picture

I have a picture which is on SharePoint which is versioned. I upload automatically a new version every day and now I want to embed this picture to a page.

I tried to do it by clicking on the picture and then view original and taking the URL of that picture because it's static, just the SharePoint folder structure and name. Of course when there is a newer version it still takes the version one, but when I delete all the versions and do the same process I will get the old picture even when it's only one version there.

I don't have access to recycle bin in that space nor to clear cache. Is there a way to get the latest version of my picture always with a static link?

You can suggest anything, I could talk to global admin to change it for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there check-in/checkout enabled? are you publishing the newly uploaded image automatically? Also you need to refresh (maybe hard refresh `Ctrl + F5`) the page after new image is uploaded to reflect on the sharepoint page.

Comment: The hard refresh seems to be working. I will check more examples.

Comment: Yup. It is working for all. Thanks.

Comment: Great. glad it worked for you. I have added it as an answer below. Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below things to troubleshoot your issue:

1. If there is check-in/check-out enable then please check-in the image file after upload (and publish the file).
2. Also you need to refresh (maybe hard refresh `Ctrl + F5`) the page after new image is uploaded to reflect on the SharePoint page.